# Golang: Testing several times using gobench

Tags: go

I'm  working with [gobench](https://github.com/cmpxchg16/gobench), wich help us to test a request and have several measures about the performance.

I did a modification for send the url that I need test in each call. But I found that it's not posible call the function twice or more times.

```
func GobenchMain(currectRoute *string) {
    startTime := time.Now()

    var done sync.WaitGroup
    results := make(map[int]*Result)
...
}
```

After that I realize that the problem on gobench file is on this part:

```
signalChannel := make(chan os.Signal, 2)
    signal.Notify(signalChannel, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)
    go func() {
        _ = <-signalChannel
        printResults(results, startTime)
        os.Exit(0)
    }()
```

Finally this is the way that I expect to do the call, and with this make more that one request.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gobench"
)

var searchRoutes = []string{
    "http:www.myurl.com/request1",
    "http:www.myurl.com/request2",
    "http:www.myurl.com/request3",
    "http:www.myurl.com/request4",
}

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < len(searchRoutes); i++ {
        gobench.GobenchMain(&searchRoutes[i])
    }
...
}
```

How can I call more that one time my GobeachMain?
;Currently with the code like that It's only possible call once, because after gobench get the result goes on os.exit(0), and if I remove this line, the program just goes to stand by

Comment: and the question is ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gobench` was never designed to be used as a library.

Just call the binary something like this

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func gobench(url string) {
    cmd := exec.Command("gobench", url)
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Command finished with error: %v", err)
    }
}

var searchRoutes = []string{
    "http:www.myurl.com/request1",
    "http:www.myurl.com/request2",
    "http:www.myurl.com/request3",
    "http:www.myurl.com/request4",
}

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < len(searchRoutes); i++ {
        gobench(searchRoutes[i])
    }
}
```