# Golang: Execute the gobench on binary mode

Tags: go

I'm working in a script in which I want to make several calls to [gobench](https://github.com/cmpxchg16/gobench), I received the advice that I should read on the binary way, like that

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func gobench(url string) {
    cmd := exec.Command("gobench", url)
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Command finished with error: %v", err)
    }
}

var searchRoutes = []string{
    "http:www.myurl.com/request1",
    "http:www.myurl.com/request2",
    "http:www.myurl.com/request3",
    "http:www.myurl.com/request4",
}

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < len(searchRoutes); i++ {
        gobench(searchRoutes[i])
    }
}
```

But once I'm do it this I'm getting this error, Does anybody knows why?

> 2014/06/03 12:02:44 Command finished with error: exec: "gobench":
>   executable file not found in $PATH

Are there any other way to do the exc without setting the gobench as value in the PATH?

If I export my gobench dir to my PATH I'm receiving this

> 2014/06/03 12:22:59 Command finished with error: exit status 2 exit
>   status 1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Golang: Testing several times using gobench](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004783/golang-testing-several-times-using-gobench)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the whole directory where gobench resides to `exec.Command()`:

```
func gobench(url string) {
    cmd := exec.Command("/path/to/gobench", url)
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Command finished with error: %v", err)
    }
}
```